# Meaning of a conversation "if it isn't sweet little"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching an episode of an anime. I came across a conversation  which seemed to be confusing. The conversation was between two girls who were each other's competitors. Ursula and Dawn are the names of those two girls. Ursula and Dawn have taken part in a contest. Dawn wins the first round of that contest. After winning, she meets Ursula backstage and have a conversation.

*The conversation was this-:*

***Ursula*** - *My, My, what do you know? If it isn't sweet little Dawn.*

***Dawn*** - *Ursula!*

***Ursula*** - *I have the less than great pleasure of seeing your performance yesterday; as usual sheer dumb luck appears to have gotten you pass the first round. I hate to burst bubble but you are hardly capable of winning the final round.*
   ***----------------------------------------------------------------***

***The video link is here; the dialogue took place at 4:33 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_ruXTg9Jfw&feature=youtube_gdata_player***

I could not understand what Ursula meant by **if it isn't sweet little Dawn**. What did she mean to say? Is that an idiom?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you asking why Ursula said "If it isn't...", or is it the "sweet little" bit you're confused about? Or both?

From the context you've provided, it sounds like Ursula was using "sweet little" as a mocking pejorative, perhaps implying that Dawn is weak or overly saccharine, which Ursula finds unpleasant.

If it's the 'if it isn't...' part you're confused about, this is an idiomatic way of expressing surprise (or perhaps feigned surprise) at the presence of someone or something.

Comment: General Reference. [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/if) **if** 6: *Expressing surprise or regret: Example, **well, if it isn’t Frank!***. BTW, Vinnie, "Ursula" in your example is either carelessly, uneducated, or not a native speaker. Her text is riddled with errors and shortcomings.

Comment: Ursula is a native speaker. That anime is made in the US. "If it isn't" is not matching with "sweet little", am I right?

Comment: Is this an American anime? I don't watch anime but I do know a lot of it is  subtitled or dubbed over in English. I ask this because "Ursula" seems to have a very strange dialogue (as in, it doesn't seem native).  Possibly written/ translated by a non-native speaker?

Comment: "Ursula" that was said by Dawn not as a word, she just called her name because she was talking to her friends and accidentally Ursula started insulting her from her behind; that's why she said "Ursula".

Comment: I have got the video link. That dialogue was spoken at 4:33 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_ruXTg9Jfw&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Both "sweet" and "little", in the proper context, can be words of affection, and the combo "sweet little" is not uncommon when referring to a child of perhaps 5 years of age. Use for older people can, of course, be sarcastic, though there are cases where the term might reasonably be used affectionately for adults.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of sarcasm. "Sweet" is a generally positive word and "little" can also have an affectionate meaning. In this context, Ursula is being sarcastic, so the phrase is intended to be insulting.

Comment: Okay, thank you but why did she use "if it isn't"? Does "if it isn't" have any affect on that sentence?

Comment: It would sound odd to meet someone and say to her, "It is Dawn!" As a result, some people use the idiom "If it isn't Dawn!" as a friendly greeting.

Comment: I *think* that "If it isn't ..." implies certainty.  So "If it isn't Jack Smith!" might be used when someone who hasn't been seen for a while walks into a bar, and implies "If it isn't Jack Smith, I'll be really surprised!" [with the suggestion that the speaker momentarily failed to recognize Jack Smith]

Comment: ... but I agree that the "sweet little" is being used sarcastically.

Comment: Maybe I would have heard something wrong. I have got the link of the video, the dialogue was spoken at 4:33 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_ruXTg9Jfw&feature=youtube_gdata_player